# Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getView()Landroid/view/View;)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dialog, material-design

I am trying to convert a Java file to Kotlin just when I encounter this issue coming from the constructor parameter `var view: View`. I have seen similar issues but have not encountered one that uses a dialog as I have used here. It's important that I pass a view as a contractor parameter because I use that view for an important feature that depends on the dialog behavior. 
**Before converting to Kotlin**

```
ackage com.indupendo.landing.ui.dialogs;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder;
import com.indupendo.R;
import com.indupendo.databinding.DialogLoginBinding;
import com.indupendo.globals.utilities.Utils;

public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment {

    DialogLoginBinding binding;
    View view;

    public LoginDialog(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DialogLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireActivity(),
                R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_rounded);
        dialogBuilder.setView(binding.getRoot());

        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> {
            Utils.INSTANCE.showLoginCancellationSnackBar(view, getLayoutInflater());
            dialog.cancel();
        });

        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Login", (dialog, which) -> Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Logged In",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());

        return dialogBuilder.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancel(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
        Utils.INSTANCE.showLoginCancellationSnackBar(view, getLayoutInflater());
        dialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

**After conversion**

```
package com.indupendo.landing.ui.fragments

import android.app.Dialog
import com.indupendo.globals.utilities.Utils.showLoginCancellationSnackBar
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder
import com.indupendo.R
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import com.indupendo.databinding.DialogLoginBinding

class LoginDialog(var view: View) : DialogFragment() {
    var binding: DialogLoginBinding? = null
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        binding = DialogLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val dialogBuilder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(
            requireActivity(),
            R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_rounded
        )
        dialogBuilder.setView(binding!!.getRoot())
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int ->
            showLoginCancellationSnackBar(
                view, layoutInflater
            )
            dialog.cancel()
        }
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Login") { dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int ->
            Toast.makeText(
                activity,
                "Logged In",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
        return dialogBuilder.create()
    }

    override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        super.onCancel(dialog)
        showLoginCancellationSnackBar(view, layoutInflater)
        dialog.cancel()
    }
}
```

How can I rewrite the Kotlin class and achieve the same result but without this bug?

Comment: Did you try changing the name? view to mView and then use this mView where you want. I think it’s because of variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using constructor with properties like this

```kotlin
class LoginDialog(var propertyName: View)
```

Kotlin is trying to create getters and setters for them. And their names will be `getPropertyName()` and `setPropertyName()`.

In your example getter getView() is conflicting with the method from one of your base classes - Fragment.java:

```
/**
 * Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by {@link #onCreateView}),
 * if provided.
 *
 * @return The fragment's root view, or null if it has no layout.
 */
@Nullable
public View getView() {
    return mView;
}
```

You have several options how to fix this error:

1. Just change the property name

```
class LoginDialog(var myView: View)
```

2. Replace property initialization with simple parameter and init the property manually

```
class LoginDialog(view: View) : DialogFragment() {
var myView: View = view
    get() = field
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
```

3. Annotate your property with the `@JvmField` annotation. This will instructs the Kotlin compiler not to generate getters/setters for this property and expose it as a field

```
class LoginDialog(@JvmField internal val view: View) : DialogFragment() {
```

And a little off topic:

Though the options above could solve the error, there is more major issue with this class - sending a parameter to the Fragment constructor is a rather dangerous decision. From the Google spec:

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the no-argument constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state restore.

You can follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I took @DmitryArc's answer above into consideration and thought of a safer solution following their **PS: "All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument constructor."**
Instead of having to pass a constructor parameter,  a way around this is having to access the view of the hosting activity, a button in my case, through `requireActivity()` function and `findViewById(...)`.

```
package com.indupendo.landing.ui.dialogs

import android.app.Dialog
import com.indupendo.globals.utilities.Utils.showLoginCancellationSnackBar
import android.os.Bundle
import com.indupendo.R
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import com.indupendo.databinding.DialogLoginBinding

class LoginDialog : DialogFragment() {
    var binding: DialogLoginBinding? = null
    private var snackBarView: Button? = null // This is required by snackBar as an argument

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        snackBarView = requireActivity().findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_login) as Button
        binding = DialogLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val dialogBuilder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(
            requireActivity(),
            R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_rounded
        )
        dialogBuilder.setView(binding!!.getRoot())
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
            showLoginCancellationSnackBar(
                snackBarView!!, layoutInflater
            )
            dialog.cancel()
        }
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Login") { _: DialogInterface?, _: Int ->
            Toast.makeText(
                activity,
                "Logged In",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
        return dialogBuilder.create()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        snackBarView = requireActivity().findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_login) as Button
    }

    override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        super.onCancel(dialog)
        showLoginCancellationSnackBar(snackBarView!!, layoutInflater)
        dialog.cancel()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding = null
        snackBarView = null
    }
}
```

**PS: Anyone is welcome to improve this answer!**